# Criação de Array em kotlin : No value passed for parameter array [init]

Tags: java, array, kotlin, conversão

`kotlin array`

```
Converti um código de java para kotlin, porém está com um erro que não consigo resolver
```

Aqui está o código em java

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Button btnNext;
    private ImageView[] vectorImage;
    private LinearLayout containerDots;
    private Drawable active;
    private Drawable inactive;
    private SliderFragmentAdapter adapterFragment;
    private int lengthSlide;
    private Button btnSkip;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
        initViews();
        configSlideAdapter();
        configNextSlideButton();
        configVetorImgSlid();
        configSkipOnboardingButton();
    }

    private void configSkipOnboardingButton() {
        btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finishOnboardin();
            }
        });
    }

    private void finishOnboardin() {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void configVetorImgSlid() {
        lengthSlide = adapterFragment.getCount();
        vectorImage = new ImageView[lengthSlide];
        prepareDots();
    }

    private void prepareDots() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthSlide; i++) {
            vectorImage[i] = new ImageView(this);
            vectorImage[i].setImageDrawable(inactive);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 0);
            containerDots.addView(vectorImage[i], layoutParams);
        }
        vectorImage[0].setImageDrawable(active);
    }


    private void configSlideAdapter() {
        adapterFragment = new SliderFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 4);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterFragment);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                for (int i = 0; i < lengthSlide; i++) {
                    vectorImage[i].setImageDrawable(inactive);
                }
                vectorImage[position].setImageDrawable(active);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });
    }

    private void initViews() {
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPage);
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        containerDots = findViewById(R.id.container_dots);
        active = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.active_dot);
        inactive = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.inactive_dots);
        btnSkip = findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    }
    private void configNextSlideButton() {
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int currentSlide = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentSlide + 1);
                if (currentSlide == (lengthSlide - 1)) {
                    finishOnboardin();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

`Código em Kotlin`
Convertido fica desta forma

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
import br.com.brq.brqmotors.onboarding.Adapter.ViewPagerAdapter


class OnboardingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var viewPager: ViewPager? = null
    private var btnNext: Button? = null
    private var vectorImage: Array<ImageView>? = null
    private var containerDots: LinearLayout? = null
    private var active: Drawable? = null
    private var inactive: Drawable? = null
    private var adapterFragment: ViewPagerAdapter? = null
    private var lengthSlide: Int = 0
    private var btnSkip: Button? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(br.com.brq.brqmotors.R.layout.activity_onboarding)
        initViews()
        configSlideAdapter()
        configNextSlideButton()
        configVetorImgSlid()
        configSkipOnboardingButton()
    }

    private fun configSkipOnboardingButton() {
        btnSkip!!.setOnClickListener { finishOnboarding() }
    }

    private fun finishOnboarding() {
        finish()
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, javaClass::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

private fun configVetorImgSlid() {
    lengthSlide = adapterFragment.getCount()
    vectorImage = arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(lengthSlide)
    prepareDots()
}

private fun prepareDots() {
        for (i in 0 until lengthSlide) {
            vectorImage?.set(i, ImageView(this))
            vectorImage!![i].setImageDrawable(inactive)

            val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            layoutParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 0)
            containerDots!!.addView(vectorImage!![i], layoutParams)
        }
        vectorImage!![0].setImageDrawable(active)
    }


    private fun configSlideAdapter() {
        adapterFragment = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, 4)
        viewPager!!.adapter = adapterFragment
        viewPager!!.addOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                for (i in 0 until lengthSlide) {
                    vectorImage!![i].setImageDrawable(inactive)
                }
                vectorImage!![position].setImageDrawable(active)
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
        })
    }

    private fun initViews() {
        viewPager = findViewById(br.com.brq.brqmotors.R.id.viewPagerPrincipal)
        btnNext = findViewById(br.com.brq.brqmotors.R.id.btn_proximo)
        containerDots = findViewById(br.com.brq.brqmotors.R.id.container_pontos)
        btnSkip = findViewById(br.com.brq.brqmotors.R.id.btn_pular)
    }

    private fun configNextSlideButton() {
        btnNext!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val currentSlide = viewPager!!.currentItem
            viewPager!!.currentItem = currentSlide + 1
            if (currentSlide == lengthSlide - 1) {
                finishOnboarding()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

> O erro se encontra aqui

```
 private fun configVetorImgSlid() {
    lengthSlide = adapterFragment.getCount()
    vectorImage = arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(lengthSlide)
    prepareDots()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O trecho está com erro porque vectorImage foi declarado como `Array<ImageView>?`, que significa que o valor da variável pode ser nulo (por exemplo, pode ter ou não uma array ali) mas o conteúdo da array não pode conter nulo, logo, se uma array estiver na varável, nenhum deles poderá ser nulo e quando você tenta atribuir `arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(lengthSlide)` a ela, você está passando uma array de tamanho `lengthSlide` que aceita nulo no conteúdo e está totalmente preenchida com nulo.

Algumas possíveis declarações, não são todas as possibilidades mas já dá uma ideia:

```kotlin
var vectorImage: Array<ImageView>? = null // Pode ser nula mas o conteúdo não. Iniciada nula
var vectorImage: Array<ImageView?>? = null // Pode ser nula e o conteúdo também. Iniciada nula
var vectorImage: Array<ImageView> // Não pode ser nula e nem seu conteúdo. Tem que iniciar no init
var vectorImage: Array<ImageView?> // Não pode ser nula mas seu conteúdo pode. Tem que iniciar no init
var vectorImage = emptyArray<ImageView>() // Não pode ser nula e nem seu conteúdo. Iniciada vazia
var vectorImage = emptyArray<ImageView?>() // Não pode ser nula mas seu conteúdo pode. Iniciada vazia
```

Você também pode marcar a variável como `lateinit` para dizer ao kotlin que ela vai iniciar nula mas depois vai receber um valor não-nulo e nunca mais será nula. Se algo tentar acessar ela antes dela ser iniciada, será disparado uma exception (apesar de iniciar nula, ela nunca vai retornar null)

```kotlin
// Não pode ser nula mas seu conteúdo pode. Iniciada quando quiser.
lateinit var vectorImage: Array<ImageView?>
```